# Removing tags from text with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've this code to extract a song name from NightBot's channel page:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get ('https://nightbot.tv/t/tonyxzero/song_requests')

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
list_item=soup.select("h4 > strong.ng-binding")
print (list_item)
name = list_item.text.strip()
print (name)
```

But when i run it, shows me something like this:

```
[<strong class="ng-binding">Jamiroquai - Virtual Insanity (Official Video)<!-- ngIf: currentSong.track.artist --><span class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="currentSong.track.artist" style=""> — JamiroquaiVEVO</span><!-- end ngIf: currentSong.track.artist --></strong>]
```

And them this:

`AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Theres another way to just show the text without the tags?

Comment: share output of soup variable

Comment: execute my code snippet and let me if it works, in case it fails shares error details

Comment: list_item is not a single element, and has no attribute 'text'.  name = list_item[0].text.strip()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get ('https://nightbot.tv/t/tonyxzero/song_requests')

html = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
name=soup.find('strong',{'class':'ng-binding'}).text
#print (list_item)
#name = list_item.text.strip()
print (name)
```

Comment: not sure which tag you want,just try to change tag in code see if you get the required one

Answer (score 1):

`soup.select()` returns list of elements to not the element.To get each element value you need to iterate.

```
list_item=soup.select("h4 > strong.ng-binding")
print (list_item)
for item in list_item:
  name = item.text.strip()
  print (name)
```